# google User Request Authentication Oauth local language changes

Tags: google-oauth

I created the API project in using API console for google. And Whenever I run the gmail request authentication page, always display in English.

But I created another one and now the request authentication page is in Vietnam Language. So I check the url , `hl=vi`. I never make changes to the google account and my language is English.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom+https://mail.google.com/&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://www.test.com/getdata&approval_prompt=force&state=/profile&client_id=123xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com&hl=vi&from_login=1&as=1234&pli=1
```

I also check the API console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:123456:access) for the setting too, but don't have.

Any idea to set the home language to English ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "hl=vi" from the authentication URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth.